# Networkx graph with fixed assortativity

Tags: python, networkx

Could anyone help me with generating graphs of predetermined assortativity using networkx? I want to show as an example that two networks with the same density and average centrality can have very different assortativities. Is there any way of generating these graphs using networkx? Thanks, Rajat.

Comment: There's no algorithm in Networkx to generate such graphs. Rather, you'd be better off simply making some on your own using some standard algorithm.

Comment: I should also note its a lot easier to control the associativity when dealing with adjacency matrices than graphs.